# Python Bokeh iterate over lat/lgn list and Geomap plot them

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a list of random lat and lng values:

```
  values_list =  [['54.866451477248', '14.960403166572'],
     ['54.864632875802', '14.961946867018'],
     ['54.954669039256', '14.948996004456'],
     ['55.062464907296', '14.942403568565'],
     ['54.8500632', '14.8440791'],
     ['55.4865391', '14.4950162'],
     ['55.136166', '14.007264'],
     ['55.333691003583', '14.76279273417'],
     ['54.931334101644', '14.881326183346']]
```

I would like to loop through these coordinates and plot all of them on a bokeh geo map, managed to do it for one lat/lgn pair, but would like to make a function that would loop through all of those coordinates and plot them all on an map.

```
from pyproj import Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:3857")
lat, lgn = transformer.transform('values_list[0][0],values_list[0][0]) # transform the cooradinates


from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors


#tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)
tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.STAMEN_TONER_BACKGROUND)
# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
m = figure(plot_width=800, 
           plot_height=400,
           x_range=(-1000000, 5000000), 
           y_range=(4800000, 5000000), 
           x_axis_type='mercator', 
           y_axis_type='mercator')

m.add_tile(tile_provider)

m.circle(x=lat, y=lgn, size=10, color='red')

show(m)
```

THank you!

Comment: I think that should be straightforward using Bokeh directly as described in the Bokeh docs, but it's even easier using the GeoViews wrapper on top of Bokeh, as in https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/world_population.html